# My regex for matching decimal numbers matches "1." How can I fix it?

Tags: regex

I got this regular expression for decimals:

```
/^(\d{1,3})(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})$/
```

But It allows "1."

How could I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify exeactly which strings you want to match.

Comment: Yes, it does. What do you intend to match, and what do you intend to reject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex matches 1-3 digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and 1-2 digits.

```
/^(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Note that I also changed your `.` to `\.`. It is a metacharacter that matches anything, and so it has to be escaped.

Comment: The backslash was there, but SO ate it because the regex wasn't code-formatted.

Comment: What does mean the trailing '?' ?

Comment: @berserkerpi: It means that the preceding part (the parenthesis: one dot and 1-2 digits) is optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

I assume you're trying to match between 0 and 999.99, with 0, 1, or 2 decimals. If there are no decimals, you want no period separator. If that's the case, you want to the above.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you don't want to force a `0` at the beginning of the number, you can use the following expression:

```
(\d*\.)?\d+
```

This will match:

```
1
.1
1.1
```

This will not match:

```
1.
.
```

With some modification, this expression can still be used to force a certain number of digits:

```
(\d{1,3}\.)?\d{1,2}
```